# Linking sysssislog executionid to SSIS Agent Job history

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis-2008

I have an SSIS package that is configured to log to SQL Server. With the package configured, a System Table is created under: `MyDatabase > System Tables > dbo.sysssislog`

This table has a schema that matches the [identically named table held in msdb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/sysssislog-transact-sql).

Within this table, each package execution has a unique `executionid`, which is defined as:

> **uniqueidentifier**
>
> The GUID of the execution instance of the executable that generated the logging entry

This is generated each time the SSIS package is run and held within the following [system variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-variables): `System::ExecutionInstanceGUID`

Sample **Logs** query:

```
SELECT  [event] ,
        [source] ,
        [executionid] ,
        [starttime] ,
        [endtime]        
FROM    MyDatabase.[dbo].[sysssislog]
WHERE   [event] IN ( 'PackageEnd', 'PackageStart' )
ORDER BY id desc, starttime
```

Produces:

```
event        source   starttime            endtime              executionid
PackageEnd   Package  2017-04-10 11:12:01  2017-04-10 11:12:01  4EDBF979-5E99-44DB-AA08-839D5DCF3F2F
PackageStart Package  2017-04-10 11:12:01  2017-04-10 11:12:01  4EDBF979-5E99-44DB-AA08-839D5DCF3F2F
PackageEnd   Package  2017-04-05 13:39:11  2017-04-05 13:39:11  9E212747-3CB7-44D8-8728-9E442082DB8B
PackageStart Package  2017-04-05 13:39:11  2017-04-05 13:39:11  9E212747-3CB7-44D8-8728-9E442082DB8B
```

Within my application I'm using various [SQL Server Agent Job Stored Procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sql-server-agent-stored-procedures-transact-sql) to retrieve SSIS job information and history. For example:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_help_jobhistory 
    @job_name = N'MyJobName',
    @step_id = null       
GO
```

Produces (summary of columns, 1 execution = 3 rows):

```
job_id                                 job_name     run_date    run_time run_duration
52916CFE-A652-4AAA-A052-738E4B349966   MyJobName    20170410    111145   16
52916CFE-A652-4AAA-A052-738E4B349966   MyJobName    20170410    111200   1
52916CFE-A652-4AAA-A052-738E4B349966   MyJobName    20170410    111145   15
52916CFE-A652-4AAA-A052-738E4B349966   MyJobName    20170405    133855   16
52916CFE-A652-4AAA-A052-738E4B349966   MyJobName    20170405    133910   1
52916CFE-A652-4AAA-A052-738E4B349966   MyJobName    20170405    133855   15
```

I'm building an ETL Admin page in my application that shows SSIS job history and a summary of the logs, but I cannot find a way to link logs, based on the unique `executionid`, to the Job History returned from the various Agent Job System Stored Procedures.

Is there a way to link the `executionid` from `sysssislog` to information held against the Agent Job execution history? The best I can come up with is using date/time matching to identify the logs that are closest in time to the agent job stats.

I've looked at using script tasks and firing custom events to log the `System::ExecutionInstanceGUID` to the agent job history, but I'm unable to use script tasks as it will not work when deployed to customers with later versions of SQL Server.

**Please note**, any solutions need to be compatible with 2008R2.

Comment: Check out this link to see if there is any helpful information there...http://troywitthoeft.com/simple-ssis-package-monitoring-for-sql-server-2008/

Comment: @nscheaffer thanks for the link, will take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following solution, which isn't the prettiest and most performant, but it satisfied the requirement I had. I wanted the last *n* number of executions of my ssis package, which is specified by the 2 parameters. I hold this code in a stored procedure that is called by my application:

```
DECLARE @packageName NVARCHAR(250) = 'MySqlServerAgentJobName',
        @rowsToTake INT = 15;

WITH cte
AS (SELECT TOP 15 msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(h.run_date, h.run_time) AS LastRunDate,
           h.run_status RunStatus,
           h.run_duration RunDurationSeconds,
           (
               SELECT TOP 1 executionid
               FROM [dbo].[sysssislog]
               WHERE starttime >= msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(h.run_date, h.run_time)
                     AND [event] = ('PackageStart')
           ) ExecutionId
    FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs j
    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h ON j.job_id = h.job_id
    WHERE j.name = @packageName AND h.step_name = '(Job outcome)'
    ORDER BY LastRunDate DESC
   )
SELECT cte.LastRunDate,
       cte.RunStatus,
       cte.RunDurationSeconds,
       cte.ExecutionId
FROM cte
```

It uses a built in function to parse a valid `datetime` from the agent job fields:

```
msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(h.run_date, h.run_time) AS LastRunDate
```

It retrieves the `top 1 execution id` from the `sysssislogs` table, filtering on `[event] = ('PackageStart')`, which exists for each time the job is executed and the `starttime` must be `>=` the `LastRunDate` that the agent job logged.

It produces results like this:

```
LastRunDate              RunStatus  RunDurationSecs  ExecutionId
2017-07-12 12:32:18.000  1          210              99A8A715-890D-4115-975F-AC3DA660770D
2017-07-12 12:00:01.000  1          215              D152C1C6-530F-45D6-B962-41784EC7D9E5
2017-07-12 11:22:13.000  1          204              BBAC73C1-1600-477E-AFC9-1F66D7CFD07A
2017-07-12 10:25:44.000  1          213              A4C69B3C-462B-4000-B2BD-8C9EB47230DA
2017-07-12 10:16:19.000  1          230              3D4D8572-E4CC-4B70-875A-C5D3B513A480
2017-07-12 07:33:21.000  1          244              D8283955-B3EB-4E6D-BFDC-8D7C0D954574
2017-07-11 12:00:00.000  1          211              553FC580-54B2-490C-BB1D-6B1F9BB35C84
2017-07-10 16:21:16.000  1          212              B9A78077-A04C-49AC-A4C6-EF6AB636D862
2017-07-10 16:13:18.000  1          255              DFC853D8-67F5-43CE-B8A4-00B846425C6B
2017-07-10 14:04:00.000  1          217              8C6861B1-6CDE-44FD-8606-18F24F339C05
2017-07-10 13:58:27.000  1          224              5A05011C-9F14-4098-B579-0E75C1E76BDB
2017-07-10 13:53:14.000  1          231              9A2B52FB-2BD4-4FAA-A4A0-40AC48A41326
2017-07-10 13:42:06.000  1          210              9BDBB290-1C84-49ED-87E6-97522DB4AB81
2017-07-10 12:06:44.000  1          215              F4D0A847-F7E4-4F2B-B328-58C387D2C50E
2017-07-10 12:00:01.000  1          241              5EC52369-9832-4718-AF92-2C502D454A41
```